# Find document type in complex structure Umbraco 7

Tags: razor, umbraco, umbraco7

My content is structured in the following way.

- Root

  - Website A

    - Home

      - Page 1
      - Page 2
      - Page N
  - Website B

    - Home
  - Website C

    - Home

Each `Home` document type is connected to an master layout template.
In my master layout I try to find the `Home` node by writing this code.

```
var home = Model.Content.Siblings().FirstOrDefault(x => x.DocumentTypeAlias == "Home");
```

This works when im on the `Home` node, but when I go to ex. `Page 1` I get an exception, because `Home` is not a sibling for `Page 1`.

Then I tried this.

```
var home= Umbraco.TypedContentAtXPath("//Home").FirstOrDefault();
```

And this worked when I was at `Website A` since it returned the first node.
But when at `Website B` I still got `Website A` node, and that is wrong.

Any tips on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to it:

```
var home = Model.Content.AncestorOrSelf(2).Children().FirstOrDefault(x => x.DocumentTypeAlias == "Home");
```

Answer (score 4):

A few different ways to achieve this but the following would be the most succinct:

```
var home = Model.Content.AncestorsOrSelf("Home").FirstOrDefault();
```